# Git push to web site issues

Tags: git

I am trying to follow this guide http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto to make git push to website.

I made all steps up to pushing to the website, but then I got the error.

```
user@user-PC:/var/www/html/laravel$ git push web +master:refs/heads/master
Counting objects: 826, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (750/750), done.
Writing objects: 100% (826/826), 6.05 MiB | 663.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 826 (delta 168), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: unable to create file .gitattributes (Permission denied)
remote: error: unable to create file .gitignore (Permission denied)
remote: error: unable to create file CONTRIBUTING.md (Permission denied)
remote: fatal: cannot create directory at 'app': Permission denied
```

Seems that git didn't have permissions to write to the server. But as I granted permissions and I run

```
user@user-PC:/var/www/html/laravel$ git push web
```

on my localhost to push data to website I get

```
Everything up-to-date
```

But how can it be up-to-date when the directory is just empty?

Comment: yes, of course, I thoroughly followed the instructions

Comment: I mean, was it filled after your push. Because git simply compares the content of the objects pointed by the branch in the`.git` folder. If has changed, then `git` sees that everything is up-to-date even though your files have not been generated.

Comment: no, it wasn't filled. at the first push git tried to write files there but didn't have privileges to, and on the second as you see it says that all's ok and nothing to upload, though it's empty

Comment: I think maybe I should begin from the start better that try to repair?

Comment: Yes, it will be easier. But you still have to solve the permission problem. On the server, what did you set the GIT_WORK_TREE variable to, and does this folder have write permissions ?

Comment: Yes, the problem is with permissions... I looked at the server and see that data was pushed to /home/git/myproject.git, but git user don't have permissions to do more (i.e. write them to web server). Thanks, I'll try to configure permissions now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the answer (using the folder names from [the guide you used](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto)) is that you had write access to the remote folder `website.git` where git was comparing the history, but not to `/var/www/www.example.org` where git was supposed to build the working tree.

So when you did `git push web` you updated `website.git`, then the `post-receive` hook was triggered and git tried to write in `/var/www/www.example.org` but permission was denied.

Once write permission has been added to `/var/www/www.example.org`, you can go to the `website.git` folder and run `GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org git checkout -f` to create your working tree (and expose your website).